How to Numerically Solve the Steady State of a Lindblad Equation with Parity Symmetry?
I am trying to reproduce some figures from this paper. like below:
The effective Hamiltonian of the system is
\begin{align}
    H_{\text{eff}} = \frac{3g_x^2}{\omega} |e\rangle \langle e| + \frac{2g_x^2}{\omega} a^\dagger a |e\rangle \langle e| - \frac{2g_x g_z}{\omega} (\sigma_+ a^2 + \sigma_- a^{\dagger 2}) + \Omega (\sigma_+ + \sigma_-),
\end{align}
The time evolution of the density matrix $ \rho $ of the system is governed by the master equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{d\rho}{dt} = -i[H_{\text{eff}}, \rho] + \gamma \left(2\sigma_- \rho \sigma_+ - \sigma_+ \sigma_- \rho - \rho \sigma_+ \sigma_-\right),
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ represents the energy relaxation rate of the qubit. This form of the master equation includes both two-photon driving and dissipation processes.
I've been researching ways to find the steady state of a Lindblad equation that exhibits parity symmetry. In theory, the steady-state structure is well understood and relatively straightforward to analyze analytically. However, in numerical calculations, I encounter difficulties because the system has more than one steady state. This causes issues with directly solving the equation numerically, as it fails to converge to a unique solution.
Is there a method to leverage parity symmetry to decompose the equation, or any recommended approach to numerically solve a Lindblad equation with parity symmetry? I’m completely at a loss on how to proceed with this.
The code that I am using to solve the master equation is given below:
(*定义参数和哈密顿量*)
g = 2.\[Pi]*0.15*10^9;
gx = Sqrt[2]/2. g;
\[Nu] = 2.\[Pi]*3.*10^9;
geff = 4. gx^2/\[Nu];
n = 8;
\[CapitalOmega] = 2.\[Pi]*33.75*10^6;
ee = KroneckerProduct[#,#]&@{1,0};
aIdentity = IdentityMatrix[2, SparseArray]; 
bIdentity[n_] := IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray]; 
adagTa[n_] := SparseArray[Table[{i + 1, i + 1} -> i, {i, n - 1}]]; 
adagTadag[n_] := SparseArray[(Flatten[#1, 1] & )[Table[{{i + 2, i} -> Sqrt[i]*Sqrt[i + 1], {i, i + 2} -> 0}, {i, n - 2}]]]; 
aTa[n_] := SparseArray[(Flatten[#1, 1] & )[Table[{{i + 2, i} -> 0, {i, i + 2} -> Sqrt[i]*Sqrt[i + 1]}, {i, n - 2}]]];  
{sx, sy, sz} = Table[SparseArray[PauliMatrix[i]], {i, 3}]; 
sp = (sx + I*sy)/2; 
sm = (sx - I*sy)/2; 
h1=KroneckerProduct[bIdentity[n],ee] +2KroneckerProduct[adagTa[n],ee];

h2=KroneckerProduct[aTa[n],sp]+KroneckerProduct[adagTadag[n],sm];
Heff= (8gx^2)/(3\[Nu]) h1 - geff h2 + \[CapitalOmega] KroneckerProduct[bIdentity[n],sx];
\[Rho]=Array[Subscript[rho, #1,#2][t]&,{2 n,2 n}];
\[CapitalGamma] = 2.\[Pi]*15*10^6;
\[CapitalGamma]\[Phi]=0.;
tfinal=20/\[CapitalGamma];
lindblad[o_, p_] :=  Module[{op, oo}, 
    op = KroneckerProduct[bIdentity[n], o];   
    2 op . p . (op // ConjugateTranspose) -   p . (op // ConjugateTranspose) . op - (op // ConjugateTranspose) .  op . p
    ];
L\[Rho]=-I (Heff.\[Rho] - \[Rho].Heff) + \[CapitalGamma]/2. 
lindblad[sm,\[Rho]] + \[CapitalGamma]\[Phi]/4. lindblad[sz,\[Rho]];


initial=KroneckerProduct[Conjugate[#],#]&@Flatten[KroneckerProduct[ReplacePart[Table[0,n],1->1],{0,1}]];
sol=NSolve[Flatten@Table[L\[Rho][[i,j]]==0.0,{i,1,Length[\[Rho]]},{j,1,Length[\[Rho]]}] ~Join~{Tr[\[Rho]]==1.0},Flatten@\[Rho]][[1]];
\[Rho]t=Re[\[Rho]/.sol]//Chop;
\[Alpha]=1.5;
coherentState[alpha_]:=Normalize[E^(-Abs[alpha]^2/2.)*Table[alpha^k/Sqrt[k!],{k,0,n-1}]];
targetState = Normalize[coherentState[\[Alpha]] + coherentState[-\[Alpha]]];
\[Rho]s = KroneckerProduct[#\[Conjugate],#]&@targetState;

rdm[(\[Rho]ABC_)?MatrixQ, {dA_Integer /; dA >= 1, dB_Integer /; dB >= 1, dC_Integer /; dC >= 1}] /; Dimensions[\[Rho]ABC] == {dA*dB*dC, dA*dB*dC} :=   Flatten[TensorContract[ArrayReshape[\[Rho]ABC, {dA, dB, dC, dA, dB, dC}], {2, 5}], {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]; 
\[Rho]m=Re@rdm[\[Rho]t,{n,2,1}];(* \[Rho]A=rdm[\[Rho]AB,{dA,dB,1}]; \[Rho]B=rdm[\[Rho]AB,{1,dA,dB}];*)
F=Tr[\[Rho]s.\[Rho]m];
data=Table[{t \[CapitalGamma], Tr[\[Rho]s.\[Rho]m]},{t,0,tfinal,.002 tfinal }];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black, Frame -> True, FrameStyle->Black, FrameTicksStyle->Black]

the code
sol=NSolve[Flatten@Table[L\[Rho][[i,j]]==0.0,{i,1,Length[\[Rho]]},{j,1,Length[\[Rho]]}] ~Join~{Tr[\[Rho]]==1.0},Flatten@\[Rho]][[1]]; \[Rho]t=Re[\[Rho]/.sol1]//Chop
output like this

I understand that this is due to the presence of parity symmetry, which results in the system not having a unique steady state. However, I’m not sure how to resolve this issue.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your help.

Function lindblad is not defined.

i m sorry, i forget it, the function lindblad is defined by lindblad[o_,p_]:= Module[{op,oo},
op=KroneckerProduct[bIdentity[n],o];
2 op.p.op[ConjugateTranspose] - p.op[ConjugateTranspose].op - op[ConjugateTranspose].op.p
]

This part is unclear initial=KroneckerProduct[#\Conjugate],#]&@.... Is it typo?

here I use KroneckerProduct to make the initial state from vector to matrix for plot Wigner function of the cat state, i think it is correct.

Sorry, but this can't be correct KroneckerProduct[#\Conjugate],#]& because one bracket is extra.

It is not clear from the paper how to define the Wigner function using $\rho$?

i m sorry, now it is correct, initial=KroneckerProduct[Conjugate[#], #] &@. The main problem is I don't know how to use the parity of the system for numerical evaluation, if not use the parity, to solve the master equation it has no unique steady state, and thus can not find the result, Maybe can use Fock-Liouville space to write the Lindblad master equation like time evaluation equation, i.e., {rho_11(t),rho_12(t),...}=matrix.{rho_11(0),rho_12,(0)...}, I don't know if it works, I'm learning it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Ok, see my answer and then we can continue discussion.

Please edit your question to include those corrections.

I re-edited my question to update the incorrect code, thank you for reminding me.

This is answer how to compute $\rho$ in this model. To show final results using the Wigner function we need to define W(rho).
g = 2. \[Pi]*0.15*10^9;
gx = Sqrt[2]/2. g;
\[Nu] = 2. \[Pi]*3.*10^9;
geff = 4. gx^2/\[Nu];
n = 8;
\[CapitalOmega] = 2. \[Pi]*33.75*10^6;
ee = KroneckerProduct[#, #] &@{1, 0};
aIdentity = IdentityMatrix[2, SparseArray];
bIdentity[n_] := IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray]; 
lindblad[o_, p_] := 
 Module[{op, oo}, op = KroneckerProduct[bIdentity[n], o]; 
  2 op . p . (op // ConjugateTranspose) - 
   p . (op // ConjugateTranspose) . op - (op // ConjugateTranspose) . 
    op . p];
adagTa[n_] := SparseArray[Table[{i + 1, i + 1} -> i, {i, n - 1}]];
adagTadag[n_] := 
  SparseArray[(Flatten[#1, 1] &)[
    Table[{{i + 2, i} -> Sqrt[i]*Sqrt[i + 1], {i, i + 2} -> 0}, {i, 
      n - 2}]]];
aTa[n_] := 
  SparseArray[(Flatten[#1, 1] &)[
    Table[{{i + 2, i} -> 0, {i, i + 2} -> Sqrt[i]*Sqrt[i + 1]}, {i, 
      n - 2}]]];
{sx, sy, sz} = Table[SparseArray[PauliMatrix[i]], {i, 3}];
sp = (sx + I*sy)/2;
sm = (sx - I*sy)/2;
h1 = KroneckerProduct[bIdentity[n], ee] + 
   2 KroneckerProduct[adagTa[n], ee];

h2 = KroneckerProduct[aTa[n], sp] + KroneckerProduct[adagTadag[n], sm];
Heff = (8 gx^2)/(3 \[Nu]) h1 - 
   geff h2 + \[CapitalOmega] KroneckerProduct[bIdentity[n], sx];
\[Rho] = Array[Subscript[rho, #1, #2][t] &, {2 n, 2 n}];
\[CapitalGamma] = 2. \[Pi]*15*10^6;
\[CapitalGamma]\[Phi] = 0.;
tfinal = 20/\[CapitalGamma];
L\[Rho] = -I (Heff . \[Rho] - \[Rho] . Heff) + \[CapitalGamma]/
     2 lindblad[sm, \[Rho]] + \[CapitalGamma]\[Phi]/4 lindblad[
     sz, \[Rho]];

initial = 
  KroneckerProduct[# // Conjugate, #] &@
   Flatten[KroneckerProduct[ReplacePart[Table[0, n], 1 -> 1], {0, 1}]];

eq = Flatten@
  Table[D[\[Rho][[i, j]], t] == L\[Rho][[i, j]], {i, 1, 
    Length[\[Rho]]}, {j, 1, Length[\[Rho]]}]; ic = 
 Thread[\[Rho] == initial] /. t -> 0;

sol = NDSolve[{eq, ic}, Flatten@\[Rho], {t, 0, tfinal}];  

Visualization
\[Rho]t = Re[\[Rho] /. sol[[1]]] // Chop;
\[Alpha] = 1.5;
coherentState[alpha_] := 
  Normalize[
   E^(-Abs[alpha]^2/2.)*Table[alpha^k/Sqrt[k!], {k, 0, n - 1}]];
targetState = 
  Normalize[coherentState[\[Alpha]] + coherentState[-\[Alpha]]];
\[Rho]s = KroneckerProduct[#\[Conjugate], #] &@targetState;

rdm[(\[Rho]ABC_)?MatrixQ, {dA_Integer /; dA >= 1, 
     dB_Integer /; dB >= 1, dC_Integer /; dC >= 1}] /; 
   Dimensions[\[Rho]ABC] == {dA*dB*dC, dA*dB*dC} := 
  Flatten[TensorContract[
    ArrayReshape[\[Rho]ABC, {dA, dB, dC, dA, dB, dC}], {2, 5}], {{1, 
     2}, {3, 4}}];
\[Rho]m = 
  Re@rdm[\[Rho]t, {n, 2, 
     1}];(*\[Rho]A=rdm[\[Rho]AB,{dA,dB,1}];\[Rho]B=rdm[\[Rho]AB,{1,dA,\
dB}];*)
F = Tr[\[Rho]s . \[Rho]m];

data = Table[{t \[CapitalGamma], Tr[\[Rho]s . \[Rho]m]}, {t, 0, 
   tfinal, .002 tfinal}];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> Black]


Plot[\[Rho]t, {t, 0, tfinal}]


Update 1. We can use function $F(\alpha)$ to visualize final state as follows
 F[\[Alpha]_] := Module[{}, \[Rho]t = Re[\[Rho] /. sol[[1]]];
   coherentState[alpha_] := 
    Normalize[
     E^(-Abs[alpha]^2/2.)*Table[alpha^k/Sqrt[k!], {k, 0, n - 1}]];
   targetState = 
    Normalize[coherentState[\[Alpha]] + coherentState[-\[Alpha]]];
   \[Rho]s = KroneckerProduct[#\[Conjugate], #] &@targetState;
   rdm[(\[Rho]ABC_)?MatrixQ, {dA_Integer /; dA >= 1, 
       dB_Integer /; dB >= 1, dC_Integer /; dC >= 1}] /; 
     Dimensions[\[Rho]ABC] == {dA*dB*dC, dA*dB*dC} := 
    Flatten[TensorContract[
      ArrayReshape[\[Rho]ABC, {dA, dB, dC, dA, dB, dC}], {2, 5}], {{1,
        2}, {3, 4}}];
   \[Rho]m = Re@rdm[\[Rho]t, {n, 2, 1}];(*\[Rho]A=rdm[\[Rho]AB,{dA,dB,
   1}];\[Rho]B=rdm[\[Rho]AB,{1,dA,dB}];*)
   Tr[\[Rho]s . \[Rho]m]];
DensityPlot[(F[x + I y] /. t -> tfinal) // Re, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {x, -Pi, 
  Pi}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]


It does not look like the Wigner function, but we clearer see that there are two states in the final state.

Thank you for your valuable time discussing my problem and helping me modify the code. After reading the paper carefully, I found that I did not have a thorough understanding of the problem before. I had been thinking about how to solve the steady-state result. Because of the parity relationship, the system has two steady states, so it is a little difficult to solve the steady-state directly. Using the dynamic evolution process, when the time is long enough, you get the steady-state result. Thanks again for your help!

You are welcome!

@gangliu Please, see Update 1 to my answer with final state visualization.

Thank you so much for your patient assistance. In your recently updated answer, I saw the density plot of the final quantum state, and the separation between the two states is visible. However, it appears slightly different from the Wigner function, likely due to its definition. The Wigner function is defined as ( W(\alpha, \alpha^*) = \frac{2}{\pi} \mathrm{Tr}[\rho_t D(\alpha)e^{i\pi a^\dagger a} D^\dagger(\alpha)] ),here D(\alpha) is displacement operator, which explains the visual difference. Your answer has been incredibly helpful and truly solved my problem! Thanks again!"
